# Angular JS regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

This question is in continuation of [Regex match whole word including whitespace and fullstop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580371/regex-match-whole-word-including-whitespace-and-fullstop)

The regex that I finally ended up using is `(<(p|li)\b[^<>]*>[^<>\n]*)\b(Cat|Dog|Fish)\b([^<>\n]*<\/\2>)`

Now, I need to replace the matched word with some other HTML.

Vks, who helped me build this regex advised that I can access `$3` variable to get the matched word. But I can't seem to make that work. (https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/12#javascript)

I am trying to do the replace in Angular JS, something that I am not very familiar with.

```
html.replace(regex, function(fullMatch, match) {
    if (angular.isString(match)) {
        var abc = fullMatch.length > match.length ? fullMatch[0] : '';

        //Custom function to fetch data based on the matched word.
        var obj = $scope.getMoreInfo(match);
        if (angular.isObject(obj)) {
            return abc + '<div class="test123" url="' + obj.Url + '" text="' + match + '">' + match + '</div>';
        }
    }
    return fullMatch;
});
```

How do I access `$3` here? `match` doesn't give back the matched word. Tried using `match[3]` but that doesn't work either.

Please note that my replace is not just for 1 string but the whole page's HTML, so it needs to be recursive.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: I have had a look at it, @vks. It doesn't work with a bunch of HTML lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the matched groups in replace function by positional arguments. First argument is the match then `p1, p2 and so on` are the matched groups. So in your case you can get the third match like this.

```
html.replace(regex, function(match, p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    console.log(p3);
});
```

For more info see the reference here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter